# I get ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED while running on my mobile. But it is running fine on webview and emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Laravel Echo Ionic on the project. 
I get ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error while running it on mobile devices but it is running fine on webview and emulator.

I have tried to add

```
<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.INTERNET” />
<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE” />
<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE” />
```

on `AndroidManifest.xml` but, it doesn't work.

and i've tried to add

```
<access origin=“*”/>
<allow-intent href=“*” />
<allow-navigation href=“*” />
```

on config.xml.

and lastly i've tried to modify config.xml with

```
<edit-config file=“app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml” mode=“merge” target=“/manifest/application”>
   <application android:usesCleartextTraffic=“true” />
</edit-config>
```

but all doesn't work for me.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It just happened to me recently and if you are trying to connect from your device to any external server (since you mention about laravel echo, then I assume that you are trying to connect to an IP), then maybe you can try this.

If you notice, the network_security_config.xml located in "resources" folder will be copied into your android "app" folder

```
...

<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
...
</platform>
...
```

Maybe try to modify network_security_config.xml file located in resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml into :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <domain>your_external_ip_here</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: wow, thanks!! That was quick reply. It works perfectly after I remove and rebuild android platform.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Comment: Still i facing that problem help @Cheezey

Answer (score 2):

```
network_security_config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">173.249.51.122</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Enter Only IP address (No http:// or  https://). It's work for me

Comment: Where is the network_security_config.xml exactly ? Is it in my ionic projects folder ? As it is I do not have network_security_config.xml Can you specify the network_security_config.xml?

Answer (score 1):

To run it on mobile devices you need to make some configurations in your project, following the file path below you will arrive at three possible solutions

resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR DOMAIN/IP</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="Scheme" value="http" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
  </platform>
```

platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score -2):

My network_security_config.xml file some changes in it you can try. This is worked for me. Add your IP address

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain>localhost</domain>
      <domain>http://192.168.0.51:8082/hbpms"</domain>
</domain-config>
```